# Dynamically created textfield validation

Tags: objective-c, ios, validation

I'm trying to validate dynamically created text fields. The total number of textfields may vary. 
The idea is to populate the empty fields with string like player 1, player 2 etc.. Here is what I try

```
-(IBAction)validateTextFields:sender
{
    self.howManyPlayers = 3;
    int emptyFieldCounter = 1;
    NSMutableArray *playersNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.howManyPlayers];

      while (self.howManyPlayers > 1) 
      {
        self.howManyPlayers--;
        UITextField *tmp = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag:self.howManyPlayers];

        if (tmp.text == nil) 
        {
            [tmp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %d", emptyFieldCounter]];
            emptyFieldCounter++;
        }
        [playersNames addObject:tmp.text];            
    }
}
```

The problems is that if I touch the button which invoke validateTextFields method. The first and the second textfield are populated with text Player 1 and Player 2, but the third field is not populated. 
I notice also that if I type a text let's say in the second field touch the button then remove the text and again touch the button that field is not populated with text Player X.

How to make all that things to work correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code for two lines like this:

```
 while (self.howManyPlayers >= 1) //edited line
      {

        UITextField *tmp = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag:self.howManyPlayers];

        if (tmp.text == nil) 
        {
            [tmp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player %d", emptyFieldCounter]];
            emptyFieldCounter++;
        }
        [playersNames addObject:tmp.text];  
        self.howManyPlayers--;     // moved line     
    }
```

I forgot ur second question, so edited my answer. 
For that try with this. Change `if (tmp.text == nil)` with `if (tmp.text == nil || [tmp.txt isEqualToString:@""])`

Answer (score 0):

The reason only two fields are populated is that you are only going through the `while loop` twice. It should be

```
while (self.howManyPlayers >= 1)
```

You should also move the decrement to the end of your while loop

```
while (self.howManyPlayers >= 1) 
{
    // other code here

    self.howManyPlayers--;
}
```

For the second part of your question, I think when you delete the text from the control, it stops being nil and now becomes an empty string. So you need to check for an empty string as well as nil in your code.

```
if (tmp.text == nil || [tmp.txt isEqualToString:@""])
```

Comment: Yeah. I fixed that. Now it works. But what about my second part of question ?

" I notice also that if I type a text let's say in the second field touch the button then remove the text and again touch the button that field is not populated with text Player X."

Comment: Good that the first part works, I've updated my answer on the second part (altho looks I'm too late to be accepted answer...)